# Fourier series to fourier product

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Is there generally a way to turn a (finite) Fourier series:

$$ f(x) := a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_k \cos(nx) + b_k \sin(nx) $$

Into a product?  eg:

$$ 1 - \cos(2x) + \cos(4x) = \frac{\cos(2x) \cos(3x)}{\cos(x)} $$

I can generally find the series representation of a product like this by evaluating it at a few points and taking the discrete fourier transform.  I don't know if all such products have a finite series representation, but the small handful I've tried do.

However, I don't know how to go from the series representation to the corresponding product, or even if all series have a corresponding product.

Comment: What is allowable? $$\frac{\prod_n a_n\sin(nx)\prod_m a_m\cos(mx)}{\prod_k a_k\sin(kx)\prod_p a_p\cos(px)}$$

Comment: @GappyHilmore that would be an acceptable form, yeah.  The idea is to eliminate sums so that you could eg: take the logarithm of the Fourier series by transforming it into a product, then calculate the sum of the log of the terms in the product.